# Evaluating a summation without calculus

Tags: sequences-and-series, contest-math

Let $S_n$=$\sum_{k=1}^n$$\frac{n}{n^2 + kn + k^2}$ and $T_n$=$\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}$$\frac{n}{n^2 + kn + k^2}$  $\forall\:n \in N $ .
Then, prove that $S_n$ < $\frac{\pi}{3 \sqrt3}$ < $T_n$.

This question appeared in the JEE ADVANCED examination of 2008. I know that this problem can be solved using Riemann sums but I want to solve it without calculus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $$\lim_{n\to \infty} S_n =\lim_{k\to \infty} \frac{n}{k^2+nk+n^2}=\lim_{k\to \infty}\frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{n^2}{k^2+nk+n^2} = \lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{1}{k^2/n^2+nk/n^2+n^2/n^2}.$$ 
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} S_n=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{dx}{x^2+x+1}=\frac{\pi}{3\sqrt{3}}=L.$$ We have taken $x=k/n$  in changing the sum integral as $n$ is very large. Similarl\ly, $$\lim_{n \to \infty} T_n=L$$ as $n$ is very large.
Note that $L$ is the accurate area under $f(x)$ in $[0,1]$

Let the integrand be $f(x)=(x^2+x+1)^{-1} \implies f'(x)= -(x^2+x+1)(2x+1)>0, \forall x>0$. Since $f(x)$ is a decreasing function so the sum $S_n$ where $k\in(1,n)$ denotes the sum of area of rectangles of equal with ($1/n$) below $f(x)$ So $$S_n<L.$$ But $T_n$ where $k \in(0,n-1)$ denotes sum of the areas of rectangle above $f(x)$. The approximate areas $S_n$  underestimates the correct area and $T_n$ over estimates $L$. So we have
$$ S_n<L=\frac{\pi}{3\sqrt{3}}< T_n$$ before taking the limit $n \to \infty$. Like the Sandwich Theorem (also known as the Squeeze Theorem), when their limit is taken, both collapse to $L$.